# Json deserializar error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft

El archivo json es el siguiente:

```
{
"resultado": [
    [
        {
            "columna": "CODART",
            "dato": "CO001"
        },
        {
            "columna": "EANART",
            "dato": "3000000063651"
        }
        
       ]
],
"respuesta": "OK"
}
```

En visual studio pegar como json crea la clase de esta manera:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Resultado[][] resultado { get; set; }
    public string respuesta { get; set; }
}

public class Resultado
{
    public string columna { get; set; }
    public string dato { get; set; }
}
```

El Código que intento es el siguiente:

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:3480/test/test.json");
            var devolu= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);
               return devolu;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           // me lanza la excepcion Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type because the type requires a JSON array
            throw e;
        }
```

Arroja el error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type because the type requires a JSON array

Incluso convirtiendo el json con la web https://jsonutils.com/ a un objeto c#.
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema.
he tenido que hacer uso de Jobject

```
            JObject objeto= JObject.Parse(response);
            IList<JToken> results = objeto["resultado"].Children().ToList();
```

Ya me devuelve un array
Espero le pueda servir a otro.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mas alla de tu solucion, lo que te estaba faltando es leer el string de esa respuesta, estabas queriendo convertir la respuesta http completa al modelo rootObject. Te modifique la linea.

```
   var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:3480/test/test.json");
        var devolu= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
           return devolu;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // me lanza la excepcion Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type because the type requires a JSON array
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Trato de reproducir su código y no encuentra response.Content como una propiedad válida

Comment: Claro, me equivoque en el GetAsync. corregido.