# Error al consumir web api con asp.net-mvc "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object"

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, webapi

Estoy intentando consumir una web api, pero al momento de obtener los resultados me muestra el error:

```
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Covid.Models.RegionsModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'data', line 1, position 8.
```

Esto ocurre en:

```
var readJob = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<RegionsModel>>();
readJob.Wait();
regions = readJob.Result;
```

Leí que el error podría ser porque el json esta entre corchetes, pero intente hacer cambios sin lograr que funcionara correctamente.

También intente lo que dice este post, pero no me funciono.

[Json deserializar error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type because the type requires a JSON array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418292/json-deserializar-error-cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-name)

Si pudieran ayudarme por favor, gracias.

```
using Covid.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Covid.Controllers
{
    public class RegionsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<RegionsModel> regions = null;
                string Url = "https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/regions";

                var client = new HttpClient();

                using (client)
                {

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-key", "key");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "host");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var response = client.GetAsync("regions");
                    response.Wait();

                    var result = response.Result;
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //var readJob = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<RegionsModel>>();
                        //readJob.Wait();
                        //regions = readJob.Result;

                        //var body = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        //var ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionsModel>(body);

                        //UPDATE CONFORME RESPUESTA
                        var readJob = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<RegionsModel>>();
                        readJob.Wait();
                        regions = readJob.Result;

                        //SEGUNDA PRUEBA
                        //var body = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        //var ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionsModel>(body);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        regions = Enumerable.Empty<RegionsModel>();
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error");
                    }


                }
                return View(regions);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Covid.Models
{

    public class RegionsModel
    {
        //public RegionsModel(string iso, string name)
        //{
        //    Iso = iso;
        //    Name = name;
        //}


        //public string Iso { get; set; }
        //public string Name { get; set; }

        //UPDATE CONFORME RESPUESTA
        public RegionModel[] data { get; set; }

        public class RegionModel
        {
            [JsonProperty("iso")]
            public string Iso { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo del json en postman:

[image: json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

necestias una clase envolvente que tenga el atributo como lista o array:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Covid.Models
{
    public class RegionsModel
    {

        public RegionModel[] data { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Y hacer el deserializado a la clase RegionsModels directamente, sin interfaces de lista.

También te recomendaría que usases json properties para definir el objeto de destino:

```
public class RegionModel
{
    [JsonProperty("iso")]
    public string iso { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Estas cerca de la respuesta. En la clase `RegionsModel` renombra la propiedad de `RegionsModels ` a `data` ya que segun el json, el nombre de la propiedad que tiene el array es `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia esto

```
var readJob = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<RegionsModel>>();
```

por esto

```
var readJob = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<RegionsModel>();
```

El array lo tenes dentro como property data